# Error communicating to server! timeout Delivery Pipeline Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-delivery

I have built pipeline using jenkins delivery pipeline plugin. After creating pipeline when i try to see the view of pipeline It shows "Error communicating to server! timeout" Error. See the image below for reference.

[image: Error Image]

I tried installing plugin again and again with restarting jenkins every time but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this happen with all views?

Comment: Nope. Only with freestyle project